If $f_n\to f$ a.e. and $\limsup_{n\to +\infty} \|f_n\|\le K,$ does it imply that $\|f\|$ is bounded?
Let $(H, \|\cdot\|)$ denote a Hilbert space which is continuously embedded in $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$. Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence such that
$$ f_n\to f \text{ a.e. in } \mathbb R^n,$$
and
$$\limsup_{n\to +\infty} \|f_n\|\le K,$$
where $K>0$ is a constant.
As an exercise for my calc class, I have to decide if these conditions are enough to show that $\|f\|$ is bounded. If yes, I have to calculate if $\|f\|$ is bounded by $K$ or a different constant.
According to me, one has
$$\|f\|\le \liminf_{n\to +\infty} \|f_n\|\le \limsup_{n\to +\infty} \|f_n\|\le K,$$
and then the answer is yes.
I am not totally sure about my argument, because of the almost everywhere convergence. Is it enough to argue as I did?
Is my argument correct?

This is a bit confusing. Is $H = L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$? Otherwise what does $|f_n|$ or $|f|$ means?

How would you go about showing $|f| \leq \liminf_{n\to\infty}|f_n|$?  (To me, this is just begging the question)

David Gao, $H$ is a Hilbert space continuously embedded in $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$.

Brian Moehring, isn't that true for weakly convergent sequences?

@Physicsuser You haven’t proved the sequence is weakly convergent, though. Almost everywhere convergence and weak convergence in a Hilbert space are two different things.

The inequality $\lVert f\rVert\leq\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\lVert f_n\rVert$ follows from applying Fatou's Lemma to the sequence of nonnegative functions $|f_n|^2:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow[0,\infty]$
